# Google OAuth2 invalid_grant error

Tags: node.js, google-oauth

When I kept trying to get a token from the API, the error I got was 'invalid_grant', even if the email and the right key were supplied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that the error was due to the fact that the time of my computer was wrong (3 or 4 hours ahead).

**So, to get rid of the error you must set the correct time of your computer.**